# Boundary preserving conformal map between surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, conformal-geometry

Consider two compact, simply connected surfaces $D$ and $D'$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with non-empty boundaries, and endowed with Riemannian metrics $g$ and $g'$, respectively. Does there exist a conformal mapping from $D$ to $D'$ that preserves the boundary ?

By conformal map here I mean $g'=e^{2\omega}g$ for some scalar $\omega$, and by preserving the boundary we can say that up to rotations and translations in $\mathbb{R}^3$ they (the boundaries) are the same, or equivalently (I guess) that their geodesic curvature functions are equal. It would suffice to show it when one of the surfaces is flat, I think.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger Is there an obvious obstruction for that example ?

Comment: I removed my comment, as you were writing, I was thinking, and realized my mistake. The main weapon in deciding conformal equivalences is the uniformization theorem, and one version of it, due to Koebe, says that if you have a Riemann surface which is homeomorphic to an open subset of the sphere, then it is conformally equivalent to an open subset of the sphere.

Comment: @A.ThomasYerger Nice. So in light of that the answer would be affirmative. Thanks. I just want to make sure of the correspondence between boundaries.

Comment: There is still potentially a subtlety that my PDE chops are not good enough to confirm, which is that you might worry about extending to the boundary in the case where there is no obvious map there. But I suspect it's fine, maybe by some form of elliptic regularity?